# fill-paragraph (`M-q`) for s-expressions?

Tags: fill-paragraph, paredit, sexp

With `M-q` (aka `fill-paragraph`), it is possible to format a single line of text nicely.

**Is there a command or function which does a similar thing for lisps s-expressions?**

It should break one-liner lisp expression where it is reasonable.
A command or function is searched.
I do not want a mode which is constantly formating the s-expressions.

*Edit:* Thanks to Drews comment I realized that `fill-paragraph` does not get called by `M-q` in paredit mode.

Comment: Check out lispy. It has commands for this: O and M. https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @John Kitchin I will have a look, but i need to drop paredit for this(?)

Comment: `M-q` does work for sexps - it indents consistently, including indenting same-line comments etc. Its effects vary by programming language, though. But it does not split or join lines (that is typically a personal style decision, often on a case-by-case basis).

Comment: @Drew thanks for this comment! Now I realized that paredit is redefining `M-q`.

Comment: I don't think you would have to give up paredit. Just M-x the commands those keys are bound to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `indent-pp-sexp`, which is bound to `C-M-q` by default in emacs lisp mode. With a prefix argument (e.g. `C-u C-M-q`) this will "pretty print" the sexp at point.

Comment: `C-M-q` alone does not, but `C-u C-M-q` does the job, thank you

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't break the lines into multiple lines and indent. This is the same as normal indent. I'm using Scheme mode. fill-paragraph break line input multiple lines this does not.